# apt-get -f install is stuck on "corrupted filesystem tarfile"

Tags: package-management, apt, raspberry-pi

I am having issues with `apt-get` on my *Raspberry Pi*. This is the output when I try and install a package:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get -f install cowsay
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs23 : Depends: libm17n-0 (>= 1.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`sudo apt-get -f install` didn't help:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libm17n-0
Suggested packages:
  m17n-docs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libm17n-0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/258 kB of archives.
After this operation, 837 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <$__ANONIO__> line 515.
(Reading database ... 58096 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libm17n-0 (from .../libm17n-0_1.6.3-2_armhf.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libm17n-0_1.6.3-2_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 corrupted filesystem tarfile - corrupted package archive
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: invalid distance too far back'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libm17n-0_1.6.3-2_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestion on how this issue can be resolved, beside reflashing the SD and starting again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing the corrupted package solved the problem.

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libm17n-0_1.6.3-2_armhf.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having this problem should use 'aptitude', even removing the .deb files won't work sometimes.

```
aptitude update
aptitude dist-upgrade
```

In this step you will be asked you if you want to remove packages with unmet dependencies or not? you should say yes and let the aptitude do the job, finally you will see that 'apt-get' will no more get stuck on unmet dependencies.

In this answer, I assumed that you want to abort installation and remove corrupted package files.

Comment: I got the same error with aptitude. Only removing the corrupt archives worked.

Comment: wait what? no remember the time I was dealing with this problem, removing files didn't solve my problem. I don't remember how did I mess with my system, but I definitely remember nothing was working after hours of struggling. @partofthething